# Can a Kineticist with Supercharge take a Full-Round action + a Move Action the following round for a total of -5 Burn on a wild talent?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, kineticist

The Supercharge description says:

"At 11th level, when using gather power as a move action, a Kineticist can reduce the total burn cost of a single wild talent by 2 points instead of 1. When using gather power for 1 full round, she can reduce the burn cost of a single wild talent by 3 points instead of 2."

Does this work the same way as the original mechanic of Gather Power, meaning the Kineticist can combine a full-rd action and a move action (the following rd) to reduce the cost of a talent by (3 + 2 =) 5?

Answer (score 2):

[Supercharge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/#TOC-Supercharge-Su-) only changes the reduction amount of [Gather Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/#TOC-Gather-Power-Su-), and does not modify anything else about the way it works. So, yes, you can combine, and take a Full Round plus a Move action Gather Power to reduce the cost by 5 all up.